# how to speed up joining large datasets on nonequal time values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, vectorization

I have 2 large dataframes `df1` and `df2`, both of which have a column `time`. I'd like to join these 2 tables. However, there might not always be an exact match. In this case, I'd like to join such that I take the latest time value in `df2` that occurred before the time value for `df1` in an efficient manner.

For example, given the tables

```py
df1
Time             | val_1
------------------------
1/1/1980 1:00:00 | 1
1/1/1980 2:00:00 | 2
1/1/1980 3:00:00 | 3
1/1/1980 4:00:00 | 4

df2
time             | val_2
------------------------
1/1/1980 1:00:00 | 5
1/1/1980 1:59:59 | 6
1/1/1980 3:00:01 | 7
1/1/1980 3:30:30 | 8
```

The final table should be

```py
time             | val_1 | val_2
--------------------------------
1/1/1980 1:00:00 | 1     | 5
1/1/1980 2:00:00 | 2     | 6
1/1/1980 3:00:00 | 3     | 6
1/1/1980 4:00:00 | 4     | 8
```

I'm currently doing this, but the runtime is too high

```py
def prevrow(t):
    return df2.iloc[df2['time'].apply(lambda x: t - x if t >= x else np.nan).idxmin()]
pd.concat([df1,df1['Time'].apply(prevrow)], axis=1)
```

**How would I speed this up?**

Comment: I just use that to number the rows as sudo-id for clarity. The reason row `3` matches to row `6` is because row `7` has greater time value (even though just by a little bit) than row `6`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try with [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) instead:

```
# df1 = df1.rename(columns={'Time': 'time'})
new_df = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='time', direction='backward')
```

*Note `direction='backward'` is the default direction so it does not need to be specified, however, this is the direction of matches we're looking for.

`new_df`:

```
                 time  val_1  val_2
0 1980-01-01 01:00:00      1      5
1 1980-01-01 02:00:00      2      6
2 1980-01-01 03:00:00      3      6
3 1980-01-01 04:00:00      4      8
```

---

The caveat is that the `time` column must be sorted in both DataFrames, this can be accomplished (if it is not already) by [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

```
# df1 = df1.rename(columns={'Time': 'time'})
new_df = pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('time'),
                       df2.sort_values('time'), 
                       on='time')
```

---

Some timing information via %timeit:

Original Approach:

```
def prevrow(t):
    return df2.iloc[df2['time'].apply(lambda x: t - x if t >= x else np.nan).idxmin()]

%timeit pd.concat([df1,df1['time'].apply(prevrow)], axis=1)
2.29 ms ± 172 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

`merge_asof` without sorting:

```
%timeit pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='time')
1.13 ms ± 50.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

`merge_asof` with sorting:

```
%timeit pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('time'), df2.sort_values('time'), on='time')
1.46 ms ± 27.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

Data and imports:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': pd.to_datetime(['1/1/1980 1:00:00', '1/1/1980 2:00:00',
                            '1/1/1980 3:00:00', '1/1/1980 4:00:00']),
    'val_1': [1, 2, 3, 4]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': pd.to_datetime(['1/1/1980 1:00:00', '1/1/1980 1:59:59',
                            '1/1/1980 3:00:01', '1/1/1980 3:30:30']),
    'val_2': [5, 6, 7, 8]
})
```

Comment: To clarify for future readers, it should be `pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='time', direction='backward')` but backwards is default direction so we do not need to specify it

Comment: That is correct. 'backward' is the default direction. But you are also correct that it's better to be explicit.

Comment: Am I reading this correctly - without sorting is faster?

Comment: The `time` columns _must_ be sorted to use `merge_asof`. If they are already sorted (as in the OP) then the sorting step can be skipped, and therefore faster. But even in the case where sorting _is_ needed, it is still faster than the original approach.